# Set bar width in a seaborn barplot

Tags: python, pandas, seaborn

I have a barplot in searborn in which I want to set the width of the bars. I thought this would be as easy as anything in seaborn, but it apparently isn't:

```py
plt.figure(figsize=(20,10))
plt.xticks(rotation=45)

sns.barplot(
    x="date",
    y="nr_events",
    hue='weekday',
    data=df_count
)
```

Now, this gives me a bar plot showing a number of events per day, colored by weekday. But if I add  `width=1` in the arguments, an error is returned:

```py
TypeError: bar() got multiple values for argument 'width'
```

How is this supposed to work in seaborn?

Comment: I saw that too, but I was hoping there would be a much easier solution to such a simple thing. I have only 3 lines of codes to produce my plot, so adding 10 more to just tweak the bar width is rather unexpected!

Comment: True, and what about the `dodge=False` parameter (second answer)?

Comment: Yes, you're right! I had totally overlooked that part of the answer! Thank you!!! :-)

Comment: Cool, glad it helped!